# after upgrading to 18.10 DNS configured in my anyconnect compatible VPN seems to be ignored

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, 18.10, cisco

after upgrading to 18.10 DNS configured in my cisco anyconnect compatible VPN seems to be ignored. I'm just getting some errors like "systemd-resolved[939]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP" in syslog
Any idea what does it mean?

EDIT:

**1) no-VPN:**

```
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ps auxc | grep -i dns
mirec     6036  0.0  0.0 334772  7936 ?        Sl   12:04   0:00 gvfsd-dnssd
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ps auxc | grep -i resolv
systemd+   939  0.0  0.0  54956  8664 ?        Ss   10:31   0:06 systemd-resolve
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=8.84 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=9.05 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=8.03 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=9.21 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 8ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.028/8.781/9.205/0.458 ms
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ping www.ebay.com
PING e9428.b.akamaiedge.net (23.211.9.229) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-211-9-229.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.211.9.229): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from a23-211-9-229.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.211.9.229): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=38.5 ms
64 bytes from a23-211-9-229.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.211.9.229): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from a23-211-9-229.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.211.9.229): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=37.4 ms
64 bytes from a23-211-9-229.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.211.9.229): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=36.8 ms
^C
--- e9428.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 11ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.767/37.779/38.521/0.626 ms
```

**2) VPN-connected:**

```
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ps auxc | grep -i dns
mirec     6036  0.0  0.0 334772  7936 ?        Sl   12:04   0:00 gvfsd-dnssd
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ps auxc | grep -i resolv
systemd+   939  0.0  0.0  54956  8664 ?        Ss   10:31   0:06 systemd-resolve
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=8.75 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=8.84 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=9.25 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=8.61 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 8ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.611/8.860/9.246/0.263 ms
mirec@p50:~/tmp$ ping www.ebay.com
PING e9428.b.akamaiedge.net (23.53.174.111) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-53-174-111.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.53.174.111): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=23.1 ms
64 bytes from a23-53-174-111.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.53.174.111): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=23.1 ms
64 bytes from a23-53-174-111.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.53.174.111): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from a23-53-174-111.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.53.174.111): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=24.8 ms
^C
--- e9428.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 7ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.251/23.324/24.847/0.951 ms
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping www.ebay.com`. Try them with/without VPN up. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Hi @heynnema, I added requested info

Comment: Oops, silly me. I asked for the output of `cat /etc/fstab` when I should have asked for `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. I edited the /etc/fstab out of your question for you. Please check the contents of the /etc/resolv.conf file with/without VPN... I suspect it'll be 127.0.0.53 both times. Do you what DNS servers that you're using with/without VPN? If so, what are they? When you connect to VPN, do you use a .ovpn file, or an app?

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what's there regardless of no-VPN or VPN-connected: nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: I added three more questions in the last comment... plz take a look for me. Also, tell me how you know that the VPN DNS server is not being used.

Comment: my default DNS is from my router, it is configured via DHCP... 192.168.1.1 upstream DNS for it are google's DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. For VPN connection there is private DNS of VPN like 10.201.0.11.   Hosts from VPN are not resolved using "nslookup any-vpnonly-host", but are resolved correctly when I run "nslookup any-vpnonly-host 10.201.0.11". My connection is configured via GUI using network-manager-openconnect-gnome. I tried to add DNS in GUI with no success

Comment: When you connect to VPN, do you use a .ovpn file, or an app? Tell me how you know that the VPN DNS server is not being used. Go to dnsleak.com or dnsleaktest.com, and does it show leaks to Google DNS servers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85211/discussion-between-mirec-and-heynnema).